# javascript bar chart bars not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I had recreated this bar chart shown here - https://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/chart-with-secondary-axis/

I have all of the data showing up, everything was working fine but all of a sudden I had changed something within my code that caused the bars to disappear? All of the data is showing when you hover over the area where the bars are meant to be, but they just aren't there. Could anybody please help me out?

My code -

```js
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
  // Print connection successful if no error
  echo "Connection still Successful </br>";
}


// Select all fields from the database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_1";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

//echo var_dump($result);
// Check if database is not empty if not print data of each row

// create array
$emparray = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $chart_gross .= "{label:'" .$row["Movie Title"]. "', y:'" .$row["Gross"]. "'},";
  $chart_votes .= "{label:'" .$row["Movie Title"]. "', y:'" .$row["Votes"]. "'},";
  $chart_data .= "{label:'" .$row["Movie Title"]. "', y:'" .$row["Votes"]. "'},";
}

//Close database connection
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    <title> 2015 Movie Title Gross and Votes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 75%; max-width: 80%; margin:0px auto;"></div>
   <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     window.onload = function () {
       var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
         animationEnabled: true,
         title:{
           text: "Movie Title Votes and Gross, 2015"
         }, 
         subtitles: [{
           text: "Click Legend to Hide or Unhide Data Series"
         }],
         axisY: {
           title: "Votes",
           titleFontColor: "#4F81BC",
           lineColor: "#4F81BC",
           labelFontColor: "#4F81BC",
           tickColor: "#4F81BC"
         },
         axisY2: {
           title: "Gross",
           titleFontColor: "#C0504E",
           lineColor: "#C0504E",
           labelFontColor: "#C0504E",
           tickColor: "#C0504E"
         }, 
         toolTip: {
           shared: true
         },
         legend: {
           cursor:"pointer",
           itemclick: toggleDataSeries
         },
         data: [
           {
             type: "column",
             name: "Gross",
             showInLegend: true, 
             legendText: "Gross",
             yValueFormatString: "#,##0.# Units",
             dataPoints:[<?php echo $chart_gross;?>]
           },
           {
             type: "column", 
             name: "Votes",
             legendText: "Votes",
             axisYType: "secondary",
             showInLegend: true,
             yValueFormatString: "#,##0.# Units",
             dataPoints:[ <?php echo $chart_votes; ?>]
           }
         ]
       });

       chart.render();

       function toggleDataSeries(e) {
         if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
           e.dataSeries.visible = false;
         }
         else {
           e.dataSeries.visible = true;
         }

         chart.render();
       }
     }
   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "I had changed something within my code that caused the bars to disappear?" what did you change?

Comment: I just added the 'axis Y2' and a few other things were changed all at the same time although I can't work out what I can do to get the bars back, all of the data shows up when you scroll over where the bars should be, but only the bars are the problem. A friend told me to try 'css overflow:scroll' but I'm unsure how to do this?

Comment: its harder to help since you don't have a working example that shows the problem. If you want to create an example that works and shows this behavior (even if it has dummy data) I would be glad to help further

Comment: Something you can try- I see your have multiple `jquery.min.js` loaded  (in the <script> tags)which you should not do, only load 1. The same with `canvasjs.min.js` Also the order does matter in which you load this scripts. I would try loading `jquery.min.js` first

Comment: Hi Andrew, I am running my work through my university server therefore I am unsure how I can show you a live working model of my graph :( above is my total code for the whole thing. Could you please advise as to how to add style to my page? I havent done this before and I need to add images etc but I am unsure where I add in the styling around the javascript? Thanks so much,,